# When should you malloc the size of a pointer vs the size of the struct itself?

Tags: memory, struct, malloc

I'm having trouble comprehending when to malloc size of a pointer vs the size of the struct. For example:

I have a struct:

```
 typedef struct {
   char *String;
   int Length;
 } WORD;
```

I want to create a pointer to an array of WORDs using pointers:

```
 WORD  **WordArray;
 WordArray = malloc(sizeof(WORD*))    //Since WordArray is only a single ptr to an array of WORDS
```

Now I need to allocate memory for each element in the array (let's say 3):

```
*WordArray = malloc(sizeof(WORD) * 3);  //Need to allocate the actual struct WORD * number of elements in the array
```

Am I allocating memory for these structs properly? If I were to ultimately free WordArray, would I need to free each individual element before I free WordArray?

Answer (score 1):

You always malloc the size of the object, and cast the result to a pointer to that.

So if you `malloc` a `T`, you cast it to a `T*`. And if `T==WORD*`, then you cast it to a `WORD**`. This logica works in reverse as well, if you need the cast result to be a `WORD**`, then the object has to be a `WORD*`.

Comment: Okay, so I am correct with my assumption that I only need to malloc a pointer to the array (`WordArray = malloc(sizeof(WORD*)) `) and 3 structs for each element in the array (`*WordArray = malloc(sizeof(WORD) * 3);`)?

Comment: @user1224478: If you **really** need to `malloc` a pointer to that array, then yes. But I can't say from here whether you need that second level.